# Selecting Cells in Table Not Working Correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a static table in a TableViewController. Whenever I select a row, it fills the entire cell with a grey color. It does this for every row I tap. If I use:

> cell.selectionStyle = .none

It will make the cell fill with white instead.

**Tableview Attributes Inspector:**

[image: TableView Attributes Inspector]

**TableViewCell Attributes Inspector:**

[image: TableViewCell Attributes Inspector]

**TableViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class OptionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var optionsTable: UITableView!

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let numberOfRows = [7,2]

let cellIdentifier = "OptionCells"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    optionsTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that con be recreated.
}
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    var rows = 0
    if(section < numberOfRows.count){
        rows = numberOfRows[section]
    }
    return rows
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
} 

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = optionSelections[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}
```

I believe I have everything setup correctly. Why does it fill in the cells when I tap them?

**Update:**
I updated the code to show what I currently have.

**Update 2:**
I've included a couple of pictures to show what the table looks like before and after tapping every other cell.

**Update 3:**
I was dequeuing cells to change the accessory type to checkmark.

**Before:**
[image: Before Tapping Cells]

**After:**
[image: After Tapping Every Other Cell]

Comment: changing the `selectionStyle` _after_ the cell was selected is not really clever; and why you could not find this consistent is because the cells are reused and some of the cells has been selected (probably) and their `selectionStyle` is already `.none` after the previous event.

Comment: @holex That was a mistake but even when setting the selectionStyle in the correct location, it still fills the cell with grey.

Comment: Try removing your didSelectRowAt method.  It is dequeuing a cell, which it should not.  I suspect these cells are layered on top of the "correct" ones.  Try using the view debugger to check.

Comment: Also, why are you dequeuing cells at all if your tableView is static?

Comment: @pdbasdf The reason I am dequeuing cells is that I wanted to checkmark the cell when the user taps on it. Is there a better way to checkmark the cells instead of inside the didSelectRowAt?

Comment: @user1715916 In that situation, you should use `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`.  That gets the cell that is currently at the given indexPath (be aware that it may return nil if that indexPath has been scrolled off or was never on screen).  Dequeuing gets an unused cell to go at the given indexPath - which (I think) then sits in front of the existing cell - hence the weird behaviour.

Comment: @pdasdf That worked! Thanks for all your help. I don't think I can accept a comment as an answer but if you want to put something about using that instead of dequeuing, I'll accept it as the answer and clarify in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, I think the problem is a symptom of dequeuing cells in the `didSelectRow(at:)` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
}
```

You should instead use

```
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

That gets the cell that is currently at the given indexPath (be aware that it may return nil if that indexPath has been scrolled off or was never on screen). Dequeuing gets an unused cell to go at the given indexPath - which (I think) then sits in front of the existing cell - hence the weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set selectionStyle BEFORE the selection happens.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView() // optional
    cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // optional
}
```

Comment: I tried this but now I can't see my labels and it still fills the whole cell with a grey color.

Comment: I should add that I removed the cell.selectionStyle = .none line from the didSelectRowAt when I tried this.

Comment: Maybe there is something which prevents this customisation when using static cells, the above code will definitely work for dynamic cells. Can you keep your label strings in a static array and set them in cellForRowAt ?

Comment: I tried setting it to blue to see if that would work but it still shows grey. It doesn't seem to matter what I change it to in the attributes inspector either, it just stays grey.

Comment: I notice you have a re-use identifier of "OptionCells" and thats not set in your interface builder screenshot?

Comment: I usually use `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to set the colors, selectionState, etc of a cell. I use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` just to add data to the cell.

Comment: @dorada I tried you edited snippet of code. That didn't work within the cellForRowAt but it did slightly work when inside the didSelectRowAt. The only problem was it was shifted slightly to the right and larger than the current cell so it would overlap the separators. I didn't have the OptionCells set in the attribute inspector because it didn't seem to matter since I had optionsTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier). I went ahead and put them back but still nothing.

Comment: I like Koen's idea of using willDisplayCell, snippet updated

Comment: I used your snippet above as well as cellForRowAt to display the text. It still doesn't set the selection to none. :/ I checked and it makes it into that function but for some reason I still get grey. I have removed setting any style within the didSelectRowAt.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an issue because you have two sections, and your off with counting the rows. Try it first with just one section, and see what happens.

Comment: @Koen I tried just the one section but I still have the issue. I updated the post to include some pictures before and after I tap every other cell. It fills the whole cell in and hides the labels.

Comment: Remove your didSelectRowAtIndex completely and test